# What does Affair means in "The Truth About the Harry Quebert Affair"

Tags: meaning

My question is about meaning of word "affair". Does it has a meaning of "case,deal" or "relations, love affair"

Comment: What dictionary are you using? A good one will provide you with various senses of the word "affair" or "affairs" including this one.

Comment: What do You mean "this one"

Comment: The sense you quote.

Answer (score -1):

The following definition by MacMillan Dictionary may apply:

***[Affair:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/affair)***

> (Countable,usually singular)  something that happens, especially something shocking, in public or political life, as in:
>
> - Several government ministers resigned because of the affair.
> - The president’s popularity remained largely unaffected by the whole affair.

Comment: The book has a love story and a shocking incident. That is a reason why I have doubts